# Integrating floor functions without known limits

Tags: definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Suppose we have$$\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^n{\lfloor x \rfloor}\,dx}{\displaystyle\int_0^n{\lbrace x \rbrace }\,dx}$$ $n \in I$

where $\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$ and $\lbrace \cdot\rbrace $ represent the floor function and fractional part function.

The usual method of splitting the function in intervals fails because the upper limit is not fixed. Is there any other way to approach this?

**Edit:**

I would also like to know a method to integrate $\displaystyle\int_0^n{\lbrace x \rbrace }\,dx$ without depending on floor function

Comment: Is $n$ necessarily an integer?

Comment: My bad. It is an integer

Comment: When you say without depending on the floor function, what do you mean by this?

Comment: The method you suggested. That depends on calculating fractional using floor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$\int_{0}^{n}\lfloor x\rfloor\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k\bigg[\int_{k}^{k+1}\,dx\bigg]=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Also note that $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ if $x\geq 0$. The case for $x<0$ is $\{x\}=x-\lceil x\rceil$ and is easily modified from this. So,  $$\int_{0}^{n} \{x\}\,dx=\int_{0}^{n}x-\lfloor x\rfloor\,dx=\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n}{2}$$

So I suppose to finish it off, $$\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^n{\lfloor x \rfloor}\,dx}{\displaystyle\int_0^n{\lbrace x \rbrace }\,dx}=\frac{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{\frac{n}{2}}=n-1$$

Furthermore, $n$ cannot be equal to $0$ in order for this formula to work.

Addressing the edit question, here is a picture of what is happening when the integrand is $\{x\}$:[image]

This is clearly the function $y=x$ on intervals of length $1$. So, $$\int_{0}^{n}\{x\}\,dx = n\int_{0}^{1}x\,dx=\frac{n}{2} $$

Comment: I think you made the same typo I did at first -- the top integral should have a term of $k$, not $\frac{2k+1}2$, right?

Comment: Well, I integrated $x$ to get $x^2/2$ and evaluated it by doing $\frac{1}{2}((k+1)^2-k^2) $ I think that is correct. I am double checking all my steps right now though.

Comment: @CSquared Isnt $\int_0^n \lfloor x\rfloor dx=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i\int_i^{i+1} dx$ and not $\int_0^n \lfloor x\rfloor dx=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_i^{i+1} xdx$

Comment: @DatBoi Just saw that and fixed it. Got a little sloppy.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Just saw that and fixed it. Got a little sloppy.

Comment: Can you address my edit question as well?

Comment: @DatBoi You can use the same technique of splitting into length-$1$ intervals -- try graphing the function to get a better understanding of what's happening.

Comment: Thats just $n.\frac{1}{2}.1$ right? My book says $\int_0^n{\lbrace x \rbrace}=n\int_0^1{xdx}$ I dont quite understand it

Comment: Oh yes I get it. Thanks

Comment: @DatBoi cool. that was a first for me too

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the usual method:

$$\int_0^n \lfloor x\rfloor dx=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_i^{i+1}\lfloor x\rfloor dx=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i=\cdots$$
Can you finish from here?

Comment: I'm not sure about the transition from second step to the third

Comment: @DatBoi I've fixed some typos, and I left the denominator for you to do on your own -- it's basically the same technique.

Comment: It is different from @CSquared 's answer.

Comment: @DatBoi I believe CSquared made the same mistake I did at first -- the floor over an interval of length $1$ from one integer to another should just be a constant.

Comment: Isnt $\int_0^n \lfloor x\rfloor dx=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i\int_i^{i+1} dx$

Comment: @DatBoi Yes, and $\int_i^{i+1}dx=1$.